# How do I improve the clarity of my post?

Tags: support, specific-question

I have a question about my MathOverflow post: [How do we create a better definition (for my definition of average) which is easier to compute and gives exact values?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358474/how-do-we-create-a-better-definition-for-my-definition-of-average-which-is-eas)

How do I improve the clarity of my post? I believe this is too difficult for an amateur mathematician. I want to make this appealing for a professional to answer without downvoting my question.

Comment: I think that ([meta-tag:specific-question]) would be a suitable tag here. Just for the record, I will add a link to the post on [math.meta.se]: [How to make my question clearer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31571) (Although there was not much response there.)